# Javascript regex: find the first 'use strict'

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to determine whether the file begins with zero or more single-line comments (the // style), followed by "use strict".

Here's my attempt:

```
var regex = new RegExp("(\/\/.*$)*\"use strict\";", 'm');
var codeblock = 
`
//hi
//there
"use strict";
`;

let match = regex.exec(codeblock);
console.log(match.index);
```

I'd expect match.index to be 0. However, it actually returns 14, meaning it doesn't recognize my comments. I suspect I didn't use the repeating pattern ()* correctly, but I'm not sure what I should be using?

Comment: Something may be unclear. `the file begins with zero or more single-line`. So, `the file`? `the first 'use strict'`, what's the second? It's better if you provide the string what you want to achieve (result).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that your `(\/\/.*\r?\n)*` part does not match the comments since you are not consuming the linebreaks, you only assert their presence with `$`. Thus, Group 0 value is *undefined* (try printing `match[1]`) and the match is found at Position 14, i.e. `"use strict"`.

Replace `$` with `\r?\n` and make sure you have no newline at the start of the test string, and you will get `0`:

```js
var regex = /(\/\/.*\r?\n)*\"use strict\";/m;
var codeblock = 
`//hi
//there
"use strict";`;
let match = regex.exec(codeblock);
console.log(match.index);
```

I also suggest using a *regex literal  notation* `/(\/\/.*\r?\n)*\"use strict\";/m` rather than the RegExp constructor notation since your pattern is static (no variables are used to build the regex).

Comment: Ah, brilliant! I didn't realize $ didn't consume the linebreak. Thanks!

Comment: Mind if I ask why the `$` doesn't consume the linebreak?

Comment: Because `$` is a *zero-width assertion*. See [*Looking Inside The Regex Engine*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah! I get it now! Thanks a lot!